# jPlayer doesn't support IE 7,8,9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-video, jplayer

I am trying to embed a video file from a url using jPlayer.

This is the code i am using.This works totally fine in the chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer 7,8 or 9.Video box is shown and it shows an error message under the video box.

[jPlayer Developer Guide](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-compatibility) says that it supports IE 7 and above.

So What can be the issue?

I tried html5 vidoe tag for this but IE 8 and below versions doesn't support that also.

```
<html>
    <head>


        <!--Stylesheets-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>

        <!--jQuery-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!--jPlayer-->
        <script src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>

         <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>


    </head>
<body>
 <div style="margin-left:50px;" >
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img src="back.jpg" width="64px" height="64px" alt=""/>    
    </a>
</div>
    <!--container for everything-->
    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video jp-video-360p">

        <!--container in which our video will be played-->
        <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

        <!--main containers for our controls-->
        <div class="jp-gui">
            <div class="jp-interface">
                <div class="jp-controls-holder">

                    <!--play and pause buttons-->
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a>
                    <span class="separator sep-1"></span>

                    <!--progress bar-->
                    <div class="jp-progress">
                        <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                            <div class="jp-play-bar"><span></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--time notifications-->
                    <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                    <span class="time-sep">/</span>
                    <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                    <span class="separator sep-2"></span>

                    <!--mute / unmute toggle-->
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a>

                    <!--volume bar-->
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                        <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"><span class="handle"></span></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="separator sep-2"></span>

                    <!--full screen toggle-->
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-full-screen" tabindex="1" title="full screen">full screen</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-restore-screen" tabindex="1" title="restore screen">restore screen</a>

                </div><!--end jp-controls-holder-->
            </div><!--end jp-interface-->
        </div><!--end jp-gui-->
        <div class="jp-no-solution">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            Here's a message which will appear if the video isn't supported. A Flash alternative can be used here if you fancy it.
        </div>

    </div><!--end jp_container_1-->

    <!--instantiate-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    webmv: "Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.webm",
                    poster: "Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png"

                });
            },
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "webmv",
            size: {
                width: "570px",
                height: "340px",
                cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
            }
        });  
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not support WebM video format.
In this case, JPlayer uses "Flash Fallback" method i.e it uses Flash Player for stream an unsupported video format.
So, for visualize your WebM video in Internet Explorer, you need Flash Player installed.